# how to overwrite windows 7 with ubuntu on hp mini 110-3100

Tags: 14.04, wubi

My hp mini 110-3100 does not have disc drive. It has windows 7 ultimate on it. I want to overwrite the windows 7 with Ubuntu 14.04 i386 but each time I run the wubi installer, it will stop at initrimfs.
Please I need to make this system Linux system urgently. I have tried virtual using virtual imaging software still it did not work. Please help me.

Comment: You are asking for an install without cd drive. Try searching for links where uSB drive is used for installation. You'll find plenty on the internet such as [this officila doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). Wubi installa is to have Ubuntu WITH wiindows. It will not overwrite windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try burning the Ubuntu iso on a USB flash device. Restart your computer and boot from the flash drive (you may need to access the boot menu from your BIOS (the screen when you first start up), try smashing F1-F12 upon startup). Install Ubuntu using the entire disk and your Windows 7 will be GONE!

Comment: I have tried this option, yet what i get is just a blinking small white line without an installation

Answer (score 0):

I have the same netbook although it started with XP installed.  I used Unetbootin (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB thumb drive from the Ubuntu iso.  I then used this thumb drive to successfully install Ubuntu on the netbook (although I retained XP for a dual boot setup).

I did not use wubi.

You have to press F9 after powerup to tell the BIOS to boot from the thumb drive.

Comment: I have tried this option, yet what i get is just a blinking small white line without an installation

Comment: Okay, could you give me some info on your system? RAM? CPU? Etc?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ubuntu iso here according to your system: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Use Ubuntu's way of creating the USB Bootable Image or DVD Bootable Image (both are the same)

USB method for windows: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
DVD method for windows: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Once you have that change your boot sequence in your bios (start your computer wait for the bios screen to prompt and press the button accordingly) choose to either boot from usb or dvd but usually dvd is the default boot device

Choose to replace Windows 7 with ubuntu and follow the setup!(your installer may not look like this)      [image] I

Comment: Note that your installer may look different but it has all the same options.

Comment: Helpful link for installing Ubuntu http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop